# Session user_name won't start or work

Tags: php, session

I am new to StackOverflow, so please inform me if i need to do some updates to my article.

My problem is that `echo $row_settings['user_name'];`  
or
`echo $_SESSION['user_name'];` are responding. I have searched around for a while and cannot seem to find the problem.

Here is my DBC.php scripts

```
<?php

define ("DB_HOST", "fomo.no.mysql"); // set database host
define ("DB_USER", "fomo_no"); // set database user
define ("DB_PASS","******"); // set database password
define ("DB_NAME","fomo_no"); // set database name

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS) or die("Couldn't make connection.");
$db = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link) or die("Couldn't select database");


$user_registration = 1;  // set 0 or 1

define("COOKIE_TIME_OUT", 10); //specify cookie timeout in days (default is 10 days)
define('SALT_LENGTH', 9); // salt for password

//define ("ADMIN_NAME", "admin"); // sp

/* Specify user levels */
define ("ADMIN_LEVEL", 5);
define ("USER_LEVEL", 1);
define ("GUEST_LEVEL", 0);


/**** PAGE PROTECT CODE  ********************************
This code protects pages to only logged in users. If users have not logged in then it will redirect to login page.
If you want to add a new page and want to login protect, COPY this from this to END marker.
Remember this code must be placed on very top of any html or php page.
 ********************************************************/

function page_protect() {
    session_start();
    $user = $_SESSION['user_name'];
    global $db;

    /* Secure against Session Hijacking by checking user agent */
    if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
        if ($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] != md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
        {
            logout();
            exit;
        }
    }

// before we allow sessions, we need to check authentication key - ckey and ctime stored in database

    /* If session not set, check for cookies set by Remember me */
    if (!isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_name']) )
    {
        if(isset($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isset($_COOKIE['user_key'])){
            /* we double check cookie expiry time against stored in database */

            $cookie_user_id  = filter($_COOKIE['user_id']);
            $rs_ctime = mysql_query("select `ckey`,`ctime` from `users` where `id` ='$cookie_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
            list($ckey,$ctime) = mysql_fetch_row($rs_ctime);
            // coookie expiry
            if( (time() - $ctime) > 60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT) {

                logout();
            }
            /* Security check with untrusted cookies - dont trust value stored in cookie.
            /* We also do authentication check of the `ckey` stored in cookie matches that stored in database during login*/

            if( !empty($ckey) && is_numeric($_COOKIE['user_id']) && isUserID($_COOKIE['user_name']) && $_COOKIE['user_key'] == sha1($ckey)  ) {
                session_regenerate_id(); //against session fixation attacks.

                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $_COOKIE['user_id'];
                $_SESSION['user_name'] = $_COOKIE['user_name'];
                /* query user level from database instead of storing in cookies */
                list($user_level) = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("select user_level from users where id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"));

                $_SESSION['user_level'] = $user_level;
                $_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

            } else {
                logout();
            }

        } else {
            header("Location: login.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}

function logout()
{
    global $db;
    session_start();

    $sess_user_id = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user_id']));
    $cook_user_id = strip_tags(mysql_real_escape_string($_COOKIE['user_id']));

    if(isset($sess_user_id) || isset($cook_user_id)) {
        mysql_query("update `users`
            set `ckey`= '', `ctime`= ''
            where `id`='$sess_user_id' OR  `id` = '$cook_user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
    }

    /************ Delete the sessions****************/
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_name']);
    unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
    unset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();

    /* Delete the cookies*******************/
    setcookie("user_id", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
    setcookie("user_name", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");
    setcookie("user_key", '', time()-60*60*24*COOKIE_TIME_OUT, "/");

    header("Location: login.php");
}


?>
```

Is my codes wrong? It works to show other information from database just not by using `$_SESSION['user_name']`. It is just like session username has not started or something?

Many thanks for your time and help

Comment: My problem is that echo $row_settings['user_name']; or <script>echo $_SESSION['user_name'];"" ..... Please finish that sentence

Comment: Thank you for your wuick respond. I am sorry, i just edited it.

Comment: Please provide us with a ***minimal*** example. 90% of that wall of text is completely unrelated to anything to do with sessions; please get rid of it and try to get your point across with as little code as absolutely necessary.

Comment: Your problem is not finishing your question ;)

Comment: why rollback my edit? There's a massive pile of code/comment on that block that no one needs to read for your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) session_start() should be first line of your code in php, in any case session_start() must come before you attempt to check any session variable.

2.) you placed session_start() inside a function, of which that function will not  run until called. starting right below that function on this line

`if (isset($_SESSION['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))`
you attempt to start checking session variables, however session_start() has not yet been started, because its inside a function you have not called. Thus all those $_SESSION checks your doing are probably all going to fail.

3.) if your going to keep this structure, then simply add session_start() to first line of your code and take it out of the function.

`<?php session_start();`  ----> rest of your code.

After that change you still need to call page_protect() somewhere, your code doesnt show the function being called anyways.

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you! As you said, it was as easy as that

Answer (score 1):

everything that is actually happening on your page appears to be happening inside several functions, but your functions are ***not actually being called to run on page load***.

`session_start` needs to run before any session reference and before any browser output is generated. Typically at the very top of the code page.

### Other Notes:

- `session_start();` should be taken outside of the function it is in (`page_protect`) otherwise you have set a requirement that this function *must* be run first upon page load.
- Your `header()` redirect should be immediately followed by a `die` or `exit` statement to stop script processing.
- Please research using **MySQLi** rather than MySQL as the later is *deprecated*. Also start to explore `PDO` as well/instead of.
- various aspects of the code are very old (2010) and really should be improved upon, such as setting of salts (which as far as possible should be done automatically rather than in the user-functions.
- Avoid using `globals` .
- Avoid using `['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` as these values are not always passed to the server from the browser.

Can you show where the functions are actually being called (specifically `page_protect()`) on the page?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10443619)

Comment: @scaisEdge I think it does, the OP does not run the function that sets the `session_start()` . That is the cause of his problem

Comment: Are you using the area of the answers to ask questions. use the comments or chat .. not mix questions with answers. Otherwise you get downvote or close

Comment: @scaisEdge OP stated he was brand new to Stack Overflow so I provided what I believe to be the answer to the code present, but left a question (*can you show...*) to confirm/ensure that OP had not missed or cut off parts of the code on his page that did what was needed (running the `page_protect` function).

Comment: @Hi Martin my is a suggestion, use chat for this kind of situation or comment is the better way..

Comment: @scaisEdge thanks for the suggestions, I will keep it in mind, I have slightly reformatted my answer to be less 'questiony'.